Discrepancy in totalUsers Metric between Google Analytics and API Integration
I’ve been struggling for days to integrate Google Analytics with Power BI. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Linkind via BigQuery: It creates a table per day in Power BI, which isn’t suitable for my needs.
Third-Party Connectors: Some values match, but the totalUsers metric does not.
Using the Data API V1beta Client: Below is the code I’m using:
I understand that Google Analytics data can be multidimensional, and the values might vary if additional dimensions and metrics are involved. Even when I limit my queries to just the pagePath dimension and the totalUsers metric, the values still show significant discrepancies.
import pandas as pd
from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import (
    DateRange,
    Dimension,
    Metric,
    RunReportRequest,
)
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Set up the environment
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'path/service_account.json'

property_info = {
     "id_property": "Website 1",
}

client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()
bq_client = bigquery.Client()

project_id = 'id' 
dataset_id = 'id' 
table_id = 'GA4_Brands'
table_id_full = f"{project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table_id}"

start_date = "2024-09-01"
end_date = "2024-09-16"

all_data = []

for property_id, account_name in property_info.items():
    print(f"Processing property: {property_id} (Account: {account_name})")
    
    request = RunReportRequest(
        property=f"properties/{property_id}",
        dimensions=[
            Dimension(name="date"),
            Dimension(name="sessionSource"),
            Dimension(name="pagePath"),
            Dimension(name="city"),
        ],
        metrics=[
            Metric(name="screenPageViews"),
            Metric(name="totalUsers"),
            Metric(name="sessions"),
        ],
        date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)],
        limit=250000
    )
    
    print(f"Fetching data for the period from {start_date} to {end_date}")
    
    try:
        response = client.run_report(request)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching data from GA4: {e}")
        continue 

    for row in response.rows:
        row_data = {
            "Page Path": row.dimension_values[2].value,
            "Total Users": int(row.metric_values[1].value),
        }
        all_data.append(row_data)

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(f"DataFrame created with {len(df)} records")

# Save DataFrame to Excel file
output_file = 'dados_ga4.xlsx'
df.to_excel(output_file, index=False, engine='openpyxl')
print(f"Data saved to {output_file}")


The data is sent to BigQuery, but I anticipate more issues down the line with this code, related a incremental actualization.
The biggest issue I’m facing is that the totalUsers metric does not match the reports in Google Analytics, whether I use the API or third-party integrations.
For instance, last month, Google Analytics reported 5,200 users. In a third-party platform, the metric was 18,333. Using the Data API V1beta Client, the value was 18,460.
Why do these discrepancies occur, and how can I resolve them?
Thank you!
I attempted to integrate Google Analytics with Power BI through various methods:
BigQuery Integration: I tried linking Google Analytics to BigQuery and using the data in Power BI. I expected to get a comprehensive dataset that could be easily imported into Power BI. However, it resulted in creating daily tables, which was not suitable for my needs.
Third-Party Connectors: I used several third-party connectors to fetch Google Analytics data into Power BI. I expected these connectors to provide accurate metrics, including totalUsers. However, while some values matched, the totalUsers metric was inconsistent.
Data API V1beta Client: I used the Data API V1beta Client with Python to pull data directly from Google Analytics. I expected this method to provide accurate and detailed data. The API provided data, but the totalUsers metric did not align with the numbers reported in Google Analytics or third-party platforms.
The discrepancy in totalUsers between the API, Google Analytics, and third-party platforms is significantly affecting my data analysis and reporting.

I don't have a solution just some steps to debug
I would check the screen views first between the sources, if they are similar you are similar is not going to be something silly like sampling in GA4 or a filter going wrong.
If you have an app and a website which a user can visit both in the same session that is a good place to look.
If not either of those, its probably to do this the User_ID

GA4 applies certain methods to deduplicate users by using the User_ID or by leveraging Google Signals, which helps identify and merge user data across devices.
In BigQuery, if you're counting users based on user_pseudo_id, Rejection of cookies and some browsers will stop the users from having a user_pseudo_id in which case its either blank or multiple visits will have different Ids

If this is the case look for a high number of blanks in user_pseudo_id you choose where to live with it or work on the sample with user_ids
